# Which linking verb to use with countable and uncountable nouns

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, linking-verbs

Here is my example:
"Cloud phone solutions work over the internet, so the only on-site hardware you would ever need (is/are) the phones."

Hardware is uncountable, but phones is countable. Is the linking verb (is/are) relating to the hardware or the phones?
If we turn the sentence around and say "the phones are the only hardware you need" the linking verb applies to the phones.

Comment: The singular subject "hardware"  requires the singular verb "is". Mismatches between predicative and predicand are fairly common, especially with specifying "be", compare "The only **thing** we need now **is** some new **curtains**". And mismatches with ascriptive "be" most often have a plural subject with a singular predicative, cf. "Our **neighbours** **are** a **nuisance**".

Comment: thanks Bill, especially for such a prompt response

Answer (score 1):

The subject is *the hardware*, which is singular, so the verb is also singular.

> Cloud phone solutions work over the internet, so **the only on-site hardware** you would ever need **is** the phones.

---

This is similar to the following:

> The **one thing** I don't like **is** *[coming home to find there's no power, not being able to find a flashlight, and tripping down some stairs]*.
>
> The **two things** I can't stand **are** *[loud drunks]* and *[icy roads]*.

But note that while the singularity or plurality of the subject determines the verb, regardless of what follows, there *is* also a degree of semantic interpretation whenever it comes to the singularly or plurality of the object:

> The **one food** I can't stand **is** *[fish and chips]*.
>   The **two foods** I can't stand **are** *[fish]* and *[chips]*.